# What is $\sum_{m=0,2,\cdots,n}\binom{\frac{m+n}{2}}{m} $?

Tags: combinatorics

and:

$$\sum_{m=1,3,\cdots,n}\binom{\frac{m+n}{2}}{m} $$

This is abstracted from a problem, and I know the answer, however I don't have any idea to sum this.

### Edit

The answer is $f_n$, the Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: Why don't you write the answers in the post ? Is the upper bound $n$ ? The first one seems to be nice; for the second one ??

Comment: Do you  mean $$\sum_{m=0}^{n}{\frac{2m+1+2n+1}{2}\choose 2m+1}$$?

Comment: Better write it as $\sum\limits_{m=0}^{n/2}\binom{(2m+n)/2}{2m}$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I have add the answer...

Comment: @Mastrem I mean exactly what I write

Comment: @barakmanos reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(n)$ denotes the expression of the sum. Then, for $n=2r+1$,

$f(n) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{r} \begin{pmatrix} r+k+1 \\ 2k+1 \end{pmatrix}$

For $n=2r$,

$f(n) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{r} \begin{pmatrix} r+k \\ 2k \end{pmatrix}$

and for $n=2r-1$,

$f(n) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{r-1} \begin{pmatrix} r+k \\ 2k+1 \end{pmatrix}$.

Now, we need to show that,

$f(2r+1) = f(2r) + f(2r-1)$

Solving RHS,

$f(2r) + f(2r-1) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{r} \begin{pmatrix} r+k \\ 2k \end{pmatrix} + \sum\limits_{k=0}^{r-1} \begin{pmatrix} r+k \\ 2k+1 \end{pmatrix}$

$ = 1 + \sum\limits_{k=0}^{r-1} [ \begin{pmatrix} r+k \\ 2k \end{pmatrix} +  \begin{pmatrix} r+k \\ 2k+1 \end{pmatrix} ]$

$ = \begin{pmatrix} r+r+1 \\ 2r+1 \end{pmatrix} + \sum\limits_{k=0}^{r-1}  \begin{pmatrix} r+k+1 \\ 2k+1 \end{pmatrix}$ $\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$ Used, $\begin{pmatrix} p \\ q \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} p \\ q-1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} p+1 \\ q \end{pmatrix}$

$ = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{r} \begin{pmatrix} r+k+1 \\ 2k+1 \end{pmatrix}$

$ = f(2r+1)$

Similarly, one can prove $f(2r) = f(2r-1) + f(2r-2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Summing in the opposite order by $m = n-2k$ gives 
$$f(n) = \sum_k \binom{n-k}{n-2k} = \sum_k \binom{n-k}{k}$$ which works for both odd and even $n$. This has a combinatorial interpretation as the number of strings of length $n$ that ends in $k$ number of 2's with $k$ 1's and $n-2k$ 0's in any order in the first $n-k$ positions. Any such string of length $n$ can be mapped to either a string of length $n-1$ or $n-2$ as follows:

If the last non-2 character is 0 remove it to create a string of length $n-1$ otherwise remove the last 1 character and one of the 2's to get a valid string of length $n-2$. This gives a bijection between valid strings of length $n$ and the union of valid strings of length $n-1$ and $n-2$ and we can conclude that $f(n)=f(n-1)+f(n-2)$. For $n=1$ the only valid string is 0 and for $n=2$ there are 2 valid strings; 00 and 12. Thus $f(n)$ are the fibonacci numbers.